# Narrow datatables by dropdown filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, filtering

I'm using the DataTables plug-in to display a searchable table on my webpage.

DataTables comes with a built in search-bar, but I want some additional functionality from a separate dropdown box. In this dropdown, I have a specific set of possible filters. Here is my dropdown

```
<div class="ui segment">
    <div class="field">
        <select id="searchFilter">
            <option value="0">Show All</option>
            <option value="beats">Show Only Beats</option>
            <option value="bose">Show Only Bose</option>
            <option value="computer">Show Only Computers</option>
            <option value="gaming">Show Only Gaming</option>
            <option value="ios">Show Only iOS</option>
            <option value="lenovo_accessory">Show Only Lenovo Accessory</option>
            <option value="lenovo_tablet">Show Only Lenovo Tablet</option>
            <option value="misc_monitor">Show Only MISC Monitors</option>
            <option value="misc_phone">Show Only MISC Phones</option>
            <option value="misc_tablet">Show Only MISC Tablet</option>
            <option value="misc_watch">Show Only MISC Watches</option>
            <option value="samsung">Show Only Samsung</option>
        </select>
        <label>Narrow by Category (WIP)</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

This filter is meant to narrow down my large dataset, so the user can search within a certain category for what they are looking for.

Each row in my table is defined as:

```
<tr class="accessory_row tag-{{ @acc[category] }}">
   ...
</tr>
```

Where `@acc[category]` is the category of that row. So if a row has a category of `lenovo_tablet`, the row would have a class of `tag-lenovo_tablet`.

I currently have some code which does filter the table, however, it doesn't filter the pagination and if you switch pages (in the table) the filter is removed.

```
$("#searchFilter").on('change', function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    filter_by_category(value);
});

function filter_by_category(term) {
    $('.accessory_row').hide();

    if(term === "0") {
        $('.accessory_row').show();
    } else {
        $('.tag-' + term).show();
    }
}
```

To fix this, I think I need to use a function built into datatables (`$.fn.DataTable.ext.search.push`), but I'm not actually sure how to implement it. Here is what I have so far:

```
$("#searchFilter").on('change', function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $.fn.DataTable.ext.search.push((_, __, idx) => $(table.row(idx).node()).hasClass('.tag-' + term));
    table.draw();
});
```

But this doesn't appear to make any visual change to the table.

How can I filter the table to only show rows set by this dropdown filter?

Answer (score -1):

Remove the underscores in your option values. Assign your datatable to a variable

```
const table = $('#table-id').DataTable({options});
```

Then inside your search function

```
table.column(columnIndex).search(searchOptionValue).draw();
```

Column indexes start at 0. No need to assign classes to everything. If you want to reset the search do

```
table.columns().search('').draw();
```

Comment: It's not a column that I'm trying to hide, it's entire rows. The row is marked by the class. I basically need to hide all rows that don't have the selected class.

Comment: Yes but you are searching for rows where the column value matches your search query. DataTables will only show rows that match your query.

Comment: What do you mean by "column value"? What value is `columnIndex`? And is `searchOptionValue` supposed to be the tag I am trying to search for?